# How to design an inpute matrix for binary classification in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to predict lane changes with RNN based on sensor data extracted from vehicles. Therefor I have an input matrix containing periodic bus data (about 40ms) on every row. Each columns contains data from a single sensor. In sum, I have more than 300 columns with sensor data.
My output Matrix with label-data contains for every row entry in input a resulting boolean value representing a lane change. So they have both the same length.

Here for example:

```
 ..my input matrix:                       ..and output matrix:
+------+---------+--------+---------+...+        +-----------+
|  ##  |sensor 1 |sensor 2| sensor 3|...|        |lane change|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+        +-----------+
|time 1|  15.0   |  42.0  |    1    |...|        |     0     |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+        +-----------+
|time 2|  14.8   |  38.2  |    1    |...|        |     0     |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+        +-----------+
|time 3|  14.3   |  27.0  |    0    |...|        |     1     |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+        +-----------+
|time n|    .    |    .   |    .    |...|        |     .     |
```

Keras needs for recurrent neural Networks (RNN) like LSTM an input structure in the shape of 
[samples, time steps, Features]

**Now my questions:**

How do I have to reshape my input matrix to get working with LSTM?
Do I have to shift the whole input matrix to the next row for each timestep?

I suppose the last 2-3 seconds before lane change could be interesting for prediction, so I need many timesteps which causes also many copies of my input matrix.

Here what I think:

```
Input matrix at next timestep (shift row 1 line):
+------+---------+--------+---------+...+
|  ##  |sensor 1 |sensor 2| sensor 3|...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 1|   0.0   |   0.0  |    0    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 2|  15.0   |  42.0  |    1    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 3|  14.8   |  38.2  |    1    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 4|  14.3   |  27.0  |    0    |...|


Input matrix next to last timestep (shift row 2 lines):
+------+---------+--------+---------+...+
|  ##  |sensor 1 |sensor 2| sensor 3|...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 1|   0.0   |   0.0  |    0    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 2|   0.0   |   0.0  |    0    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 3|  15.0   |  42.0  |    1    |...|
+------+---------+--------+---------+---+
|time 4|  14.8   |  38.2  |    1    |...|
```

Is this right?

Please note that, I will try to reduce sensor data later. This is in the moment not my first aim.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood what you need to do is,

1. Decide how much the network need to see to be able to predict, what
   I mean is you show n step and the network will predict n+1 step
2. Split your matrix into multiple matrices with n row and save the n+1 row lane change as label

Now you should have a list of k matrices of shape(n, m_sensor) which has shape [k-samples, n_stpes, m_sensor], this is exactly what the rnn needs as input.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Sounds good. I like your idea with splitting my input matrix into pieces, even though I hoped to avoid this. After your tip I think my approach must be bad, because I only can predict a state for a single row entry in the future. When I understood you right, to get a pattern for lane changes I have to create longer samples each containing multiple rows. But what exactly does timestep=1 mean in this context?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you are asking, but if you want to predict more than 1 timestep you should look to sequence to sequence models, I'm not sure if there is an easy implementation in keras, but the one in tensorflow it's pretty easy. I don't know what are you referring to when asking about timestep=1.

Comment: Forget about my question to timestamps. My intention is not clearly discernible. After reading a while I think my problem is known under the name Many-to-One-Problem with a classification as result. To sum up: I have several arrays containing a couple of lane change maneuver described by the structure above. Hence, a currently unknown number of rows (representing sensor data at a specific time) includes a pattern, which has to be found by RNN in order to predict a lane change maneuver.